# Нужна ли запятая

Tags: пунктуация

Давайте подготовимся к корпоративу.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не нужна. Сказуемое "давайте подготовимся", дополнение "к корпоративу". Здесь негде ставить запятую.

Если только в разговорном пояснении:

-Ну, что, подготовимся?

-- Давайте подготовимся,к корпоративу.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, смущает слово "давайте". Но это формообразующая частица для будущего времени.Так что фраза "Давайте подготовимся" представляет собой единое целое.

Answer (score 0):

В предложенном варианте насчет корпоратива я бы скорее поставила точку. "Давайте подготовимся. К корпоративу". Мне кажется, так по смыслу и интонационно будет правильнее. А что касается вопроса, то запятая, конечно, не нужна. Что тут отделять?